# OpenApiGenerator pojos toString method having class literal appended and causing issues to getproper toString

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class PetAllOf {\n");
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

after running openApi plugin for generating pojos , i see all toStrings having literal as class,
[ sb.append("class PetAllOf {\n");) class literal  before PetAllOf]which is causing issues to get exact request, as request also contains class literal, so how to avoid class literal in toString